# Secure logs on an embedded IoT device

Tags: encryption, file-encryption, logging, storage, iot

I need to secure logs on a IoT device (Infineon TC233). It has 2 MB flash and a HSM. We are at the design stage of development.

Since logs will be primarily event & data logs, the size of the log file is likely to be in a few KBs. Additionally, logs will be dynamic files where event logs keep getting appended.

Logs on the device need to be sent to a server or other external units when requested for some diagnostics.

We need to protect the logs from tampering or deletion while they are stored on the device.

While encryption (symmetric key) is one mechanism, I am looking for better options, if any.

Comment: Thank you for the clearer question, but you are still missing some pieces. I think you need to do a Threat Modelling exercise before you start thinking about solutions to the threats. Like, how would someone tamper with or delete the logs?

Comment: More on the comment of @schroeder above: Data tampered from the "legit" user, or "external"? Accidents or malfunctions? Protected from viewing? Say that the data are encrypted, every time new data comes, what is the procedure? Decrypt-add data-Encrypt? How often this is going to happen? If only tampering (viewing allowed), then hasing?